# Laravel firstOrNew create duplicate entry for same data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this specific code from my application:

```
if ($request->filled('jawaban')) {
                $jawaban = JawabanUserM::where('user_id', $user->id)
                    ->where('paket_id', $kuis['paket_id'])->firstOrNew(['soal_id'=>$kuis['curr_id']]);
                if($jawaban->jawaban_id != $request->jawaban) {
                    $jawaban->user_id = $user->id;
                    $jawaban->paket_id = $kuis['paket_id'];
                    $jawaban->soal_id = $kuis['curr_id'];
                    $jawaban->jawaban_id = $request->jawaban;
                    $jawaban->save();
                }
        }
```

it basicly insert answer from user to table JawabanUserM

I run this application on deployment. 
using laravel 5.5, mysql 5.5.58, nginx 1.12.2, php-fpm 7.0.27.

with 800-1000++ average user at a time. using InnoDB engine.

when i check around i found some duplicate records. i check using this sql :

```
SELECT
    id, soal_id, user_id, jawaban_id, paket_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    jawabanuserm
GROUP BY
    soal_id, user_id, jawaban_id, paket_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

the result was :

```
id | soal_id | user_id | jawaban_id | paket_id | COUNT(*)
4702 | 117 | 100 | 401 | 6 | 6
4694 | 111 | 100 | 401 | 6 | 5
15080 | 110 | 1300 | 1077 | 7 | 5
8097 | 186 | 435 | 686 | 6 | 4
4679 | 97 | 100 | 401 | 6 | 4
....
```

Any advice to workaround this problem and why this is happening?

at first i strongly believe this is caused by bad communicating between process. i have ask to my colleague they suggest using procedure, but it will impact the performance i think.

Comment: At a database level you can have a unique index for `soal_id, user_id, jawaban_id, paket_id` (together) that will cause an error on duplicate entry. However your real issue is that firstOrNew will basically ignore your other conditions and just do its own query so you need to find a different approach (ideally this looks more suited to be a relationship rather than a model)